# Is there a way to detect inactive Service / User Accounts in K8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k8s-serviceaccount

I'd like to be able to detect inactive Service accounts and User accounts by using **kubectl** / **rest api** in my Kubernetes cluster.

like for an example idle service account that has not been used for any resource for x days and it's safe to delete it.

or a user account that didn't access the cluster for the last x days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this functionality comes out of the box for `ServiceAccounts` or `Users`, unfortunately. One way you might be able to check, is by reading the `api-server` [logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs) and checking if you can find authentication entries for these "subjects" (as they are called in k8s jargon).

Additionally, you can enable [audit logging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/) in k8s to be able to detect such activities. But I believe you'll have to parse the logs yourself, through an application to be able to determine which accounts are unused or safe to be deleted.